# Where to store Settings from local.settings.json for proddeployment?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am a bit confused about where to store settings that should be used from within an Azure function after deployment.

On local tests I have settings like the connection strings in the `local.settings.json` as suggested read by the following code:

```
[FunctionName("SomeEvent")]
public static void Run(
  [EventHubTrigger("some-hub", Connection = "EventHubConnection" )]
  EventData ev,
  ILogger log,
  ExecutionContext context,
  IConfiguration configuration,
  [EventHub("brd-iot-eventhubs", Connection = "OutputEventHubConnection")]
  ICollector<EventData> outputEvents)
  {
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
   .SetBasePath(context.FunctionAppDirectory)
    .AddJsonFile(SETTINGS, optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();

    string customername = config.GetValue<string>("Customer");
    string connectionString = config.GetConnectionString("myDatabase");
    [...]
```

Now I want to have settings (with different values) after deployment on Azure. AFAIK host.json is something different as this is no per-function configuration but a global configuration.

I can edit properties manually directly in Azure but I want to have a settings-file I can deploy. What is the way to do this? Maybe I just need to know, what name the settings - file has to have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your self-defined settings in whatever files you need, and read them using `ConfigurationBuilder` as you have done. Put custom settings file let's say `appsettings.json` under function project and set it to be copied to output/publish directory(Copy if newer), in this way it can be deployed by VS publish.

[image: set file property]

But for Function bindings related settings like `EventHubConnection` and `OutputEventHubConnection`, Function runtime reads them from environment variables. We have to reply on `Application settings` on Azure portal which injects them into env variables.

Also note that, VS has provided a friendly UI for us to configure different settings in local and Azure env. We can choose to insert from local or create new settings.(Note the empty value here means there's no such setting in corresponding environment)

[image]